# Pandas DataFrames in reportlab

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, reportlab

I have a DataFrame, and want to output it to a pdf. I'm currently trying to use ReportLab for this, but it won't seem to work. I get an error here:

```
        mytable = Table(make_pivot_table(data, pivot_cols, column_order, 'criterion'))
```

`make_pivot_table` just returns a pivot table using pandas `pivot_table` function.
The error I get is

```
ValueError: <Table@0x13D7D0F8 unknown rows x unknown cols>... invalid data type
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to make reportlab work with DataFrames?
2. If not, what package can I use for the same purpose?

Comment: So the problem is nothing to do with pivot_table ? But it's the Table class, what is that? Can you give a simple example of DataFrame which exhibits this behaviour (does it work for `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` ?)

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's to do with DataFrame rather than pivot_table. It doesn't work for your example.

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to use that example instead (it would help if we could recreate the error)... what are `pivot_cols` and `column_order` variables?

Comment: Your example recreates the same error. I think it's just that Table won't take a DataFrame. I know that what is returned by make_pivot_table is just a DataFrame. The Table documentation says it can take anything convertible to a string, which I thought was basically anything. It takes numpy arrays, so I assumed it would take DataFrames too. It appears not

Comment: Maybe add a ticket to their bug tracker and/or email their mailing list. For the moment perhaps you could use `df.values`.

Comment: I have had the similar problem.  Outputting pandas and matplotlib generated objects to pdf.  Eventually settled on writing it myself and I settled on using latex as the pdf engine.  Latex is great at almost all formatting tasks.  Had to rewrite code to get pandas dataframe out (to_latex method is rather limited). Specific issues that I had to deal with were multipage pandas data-frames to latex and also dealing with multi-indexed data-frames going into latex.  I am relatively new to coding so I have rather inelegant code.   If you are interested I will be happy to share my code.

Comment: I am very interested, that would be great! I missed this comment until now, unfortunately, which is why I've taken a week to reply.

Answer (score 3):

Py

Hallo,

I'm also needing to print as .pdf some Pandas DataFrame to arrange reports. I tried ReportLab directly with df and had an "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'." I tried with df.values() and had "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable".

When close to quit the idea to build the .pdf report I tried str(df) and I had some outcome in the .pdf :-) ... The code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
PATH_OUT = "C:\\"
def pdf_df(c, testo, x, y):
    c.drawAlignedString(x,y, testo)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,6],'c':[9,10,11]})
print df, type(df)
print''
df1 = (df['a'].groupby([df['b'], df['a']])).sum()
print df1, type(df1)
print ''
c = canvas.Canvas(PATH_OUT + 'out.pdf')
pdf_df (c, str(df), 300, 500)
pdf_df (c, str(df1), 300, 480)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

What do you think ? Might this make sense or there might be some 'smarter' way?

This one seems not so effcient and I initially hoped to have from ReportLab. It seems I'd need then some way to wrap the lines .. and sizes will change ...

Fabio

=====

I'm now much happier of the below solution, while I was not happy about the above one too.

This is based on ReportLab grids, they work on lists. So the code is converting DF to list which is then treated as a ReportLab grid :-)

Here it is:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib import colors
import pandas as pd
import random

PATH_OUT = "C:\\"

elements = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(PATH_OUT + 'Report_File.pdf')
elements.append(Paragraph("Report Title", styles['Title']))

data = [[random.random() for i in range(1,4)] for j in range (1,8)]
df = pd.DataFrame (data)
lista = [df.columns[:,].values.astype(str).tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

ts = [('ALIGN', (1,1), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
     ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.purple),
     ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.purple),
     ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Times-Bold'),
     ('LINEABOVE', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 1, colors.purple),
     ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 0.5, colors.purple, 1, None, None, 4,1),
     ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 1, colors.red),
     ('FONT', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 'Times-Bold'),
     ('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green),
     ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red)]

table = Table(lista, style=ts)
elements.append(table)

doc.build(elements)
```

I'm really interested to read about other possible solutions ..

Bye, Fabio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesn't seem like a very nice way of handling things, though, especially for large tables of varying sizes. Nonetheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep :-( .. I fully agree .. but so far I had not been good enought to find anything better .. I'm new to this and my hope was to have some suggestion as well about how to treat DataFrames within ReportLab ... about the pending item concerning the line wrap I had some decent outcome by str(df).splitlines() within a for loop to draw the Canvas. By, Fabio.

Comment: Works great. Thanks